# Adding same data in angular

Tags: angular

I'm using angular , I have created 5 text box for adding hours (monday to friday),when ever I'm simply clicking (I'm not add any data) inside text box automatically same hours is adding in total hours what ever before data ,in this (blur)="calculatecolTotalMon($event)" method I'm clicking, and please how to solve this.

Angular HTML code:

```
<input *ngIf="!isDisabled" (keypress)="validateNumberFields($event)" class="form-control"  type="number " formControlName="mon" style="width: 95px;"  min="1" max="9" 
                 (blur) ="calculateRowTotal($event,i, 0, null)" (blur)="calculatecolTotalMon($event)" />
```

Angular ts file:

```
    calculatecolTotalMon(event){  
        var val = Number(event.target.value);
        this.totalColValMon +=val;
       
      }

 calculateTotalHours(){
    //var val = Number(event.target.value);
    this.totalHours =this.totalColValMon+this.totalColValTue+this.totalColValWed+this.totalColValThur+this.totalColValFri+this.totalColValSat
    +this.totalColValSun;
  }
```

Comment: you are using form with input ?

Comment: GRD,,,,,Yes sir

Comment: please create a sample working stackblitz example

Comment: The functions' names you are using in a template and in a .ts file are not both the same, only one is the same.
Also, your code is not well formatted.